# Problem with MAC Spoofing

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, mac

I am changing/spoofing my MAC using

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
sudo ifconfig wlan0 hw ether  xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

But the problem is When I try to connect the AP it do not allow me. And then my MAC is automatically changed to my original MAC.

Obviously then I can connect to AP.

What is the reason of the problem. As much as I know the networking it should be allowed. Because After changing MAC. I am connecting like new device.

So what could be solution?

I also tried from GUI, **Edit connection**

Ubuntu version is 14.04

Answer (score 3):

**network-manager** is interferring with the change of mac address.

You can automate the mac spoofing with an udev rules. It will be applied automatically while booting.

Create a file `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-mac-spoofing.rules` with the following content

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", ATTR{address}=="XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX", RUN+="/sbin/ip link set dev %k address YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY"
```

where `XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX` is the old mac address and `YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY` the new one.

You can even use random mac address by using **macchanger -r** in the udev rules.

The wifi AP may have MAC address filtering enabled.

Comment: I cant copy the file in folder. OS not permitting me to do. 
And thats my university router and i dont think so they have MAC address filtering enabled

Answer (score 0):

Considerations are:
a) There are problems with network-manager that revert back to the original hardware mac address when restarted
b) When stopping then restarting network-manager the GUI for VPN is no longer visible
c) Macchanger with switches is not working OR working on startup

So I wrote a script as follows to build a random MAC and assign it to the wlan0

```
    ##################################################
    #!/bin/bash

    #add chars to the mac
    this+=$(echo "obase=16; $(shuf -i 0-15 -n 1) " | bc ) 
    this+=$(echo "obase=16; $(shuf -i 0-15 -n 1) " | bc )
    this+=":"
    this+=$(echo "obase=16; $(shuf -i 0-15 -n 1) " | bc ) 
    this+=$(echo "obase=16; $(shuf -i 0-15 -n 1) " | bc )
    this+=":"
    this+=$(echo "obase=16; $(shuf -i 0-15 -n 1) " | bc ) 
    this+=$(echo "obase=16; $(shuf -i 0-15 -n 1) " | bc )
    this+=":"
    this+=$(echo "obase=16; $(shuf -i 0-15 -n 1) " | bc ) 
    this+=$(echo "obase=16; $(shuf -i 0-15 -n 1) " | bc )
    this+=":"
    this+=$(echo "obase=16; $(shuf -i 0-15 -n 1) " | bc ) 
    this+=$(echo "obase=16; $(shuf -i 0-15 -n 1) " | bc )
    this+=":"
    this+=$(echo "obase=16; $(shuf -i 0-15 -n 1) " | bc ) 
    this+=$(echo "obase=16; $(shuf -i 0-15 -n 1) " | bc )

    sudo ifconfig wlan0 down

    sudo ifconfig wlan0 hw ether $this

    sudo ifconfig wlan0 up

    ######################################################
```

In the Network-Manager GUI, de-select "Enable wifi" then select "Enable wifi"
You can do an ifconfig to confirm the mac is changed.
The network-manager is still visible and working to connect to your VPN.