# Spoofed MAC address - Internet disconnects

Tags: 14.04, network-manager

I have spoofed my ethernet MAC address using the "Edit Connections" option (available under the network) as well as by using macchanger. But I'm facing an issue of frequent disconnections, i.e. the MAC address gets reset to default by itself while connecting. This continues for sometime but at last it finally connects, i.e. spoofed MAC address becomes stable and doesn't revert back to default MAC address.

Could somebody please guide me as to what should I do to solve this issue as well I have gone through a number of similar questions on the forum but to no avail.

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 - 64 bit edition.

Regards,
Joojo.

Comment: Don't use at the same time macchanger and network-manager clone mac address feature. For example, remove macchanger with `apt-get remove macchanger`

Comment: thanks a lot for your prompt reply .......... but infact I am not using both at the same time, tried the macchanger only when spoofing the MAC address didn't work via network-manager.

Comment: Look at this answer http://askubuntu.com/a/629861/350004 using udev rule instead

Answer (score 1):

thanxx again for your reply ........... really appreciate it. Ahhhhhhh! the problem finally got sorted out (although sorry! to be becuase I didn't try your suggestion) but found another thread which emphasied on disabling the network-manager prior to changing the MAC address via macchanger. Here are the steps :-

sudo service network-manager stop

sudo ifconfig eth0 down

sudo macchanger -m XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX eth0

sudo ifconfig eth0 up

sudo service network-manager start

;Note - XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX being the spoofed MAC Address

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution. But please reformat.